# authData is null after redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two small web apps and I'm redirecting from the first one to the second one after a login with Firebase. My current problem is that the Authentication data is not saved and get's null after the new page is loaded.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com");
var credentials = {};
credentials.email = email;
credentials.password = password;

ref.authWithPassword(credentials, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
      console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      document.getElementById("login-status").innerHTML = error;
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    console.log("AuthData expires: " + authData.expires);
    window.location = "http://localhost:3000/";
  }
});
```

So, first I'll get logged in correctly and `authData` shows the login details, but on the new page `http://localhost:3000/` `authData` is null.

Does anyone know how to keep the session? I played around with the `remember` object but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication automatically persists the session in the browser's local storage. So when you get to the new page, the user is already authenticated.

But your code doesn't detect this, because you're only handling the case where you *actively* authenticate the user.

The solution is to *also* [monitor the authentication state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication). From that documentation:

```
// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
});
```

If you put this snippet in the new page, it will detect that the user is already signed in.

Comment: I'm using this snippet on the new page already and it is giving me a null value back. Maybe the problem consist because the pages are running on two different web servers with two different ports (3000 & 4000). The session is saved if I stay or reload one of the pages but if I change to the other (from localhost:3000 to localhost:4000) it gets null.

Comment: Ah, as you said the session is stored in the browser's local storage, so when I change the domain the session is lost. I can host both web apps after deployment on one domain, so that should fix the problem. Thanks for helping out!